# Windows service on windows ce 6.0?

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

Well, the title says it.
Is it possible to create a service on Windows Embedded CE 6.0?

I could not find a detailed information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services run in the servicesd.exe context.  Documentation between versions seems patchy; documentation for CE 4.2 can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938094.aspx), and for CE 7 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499183.aspx) and there is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446909.aspx) for 5.0.  There are CE 6.0 specific articles [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cenet/archive/2006/11/07/services-exe-and-the-windows-ce-6-0-kernel.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cenet/archive/2006/11/28/writing-services-for-the-wince-6-0-kernel.aspx) that may help with any differences from earlier versions, but you may find the 7.0 documentation applies.